# Windows 7 (c:) and XP (e:) dual boot (XP Installed first)

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multi-boot

I have a 2 harddrive system with the following **old** and **new** scenario. The old scenario worked fine, as I had a boot menu where I could choose which Windows XP installation to boot. However the **new** scenario starts up Windows 7 directly. **I did remove the c:\Windows (XP) from the bootmenu before installing Windows 7.**

## Old (XP + XP dual-boot):

Drive 1:

```
c:\Windows (xp)
d:\
```

Drive 2:

```
e:\Windows (xp)
f:\
```

## New (Windows 7 + XP dual-boot):

Drive 1:

```
c:\Windows (7)
d:\
```

Drive 2:

```
e:\Windows (xp)
f:\
```

## How do I get my e:\Windows (XP) back as a choice for booting?

## Update

**I get C:\XP instead of E:\XP in EasyBCD, even when I manually give the drive letter. Is this ok?**

There are a total of 2 entries listed in the bootloader.

Default: Windows 7
Timeout: 30 seconds
Boot Drive: C:\

Entry #1
Name: Windows 7
BCD ID: {current}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.exe

Entry #2
Name: Microsoft Windows XP
BCD ID: {624363eb-98af-11df-83b4-ac40caa654b1}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \NST\easyldr1

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit the `boot configuration data`.

Either do it using the [bootrec.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392) tool that comes with Windows or have a look at [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1).

Comment: +1 EasyBCD, it is the easiest way to correct the W7 bootloader

Comment: Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to also correct the boot.ini.

[Directions here.](http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-support/2950-windows-7-boot-ini-file.html)

Comment: XP does not use boot ini when dual booting with W7,

Comment: Sorry, I meant AND edit the boot.ini.  Fixing!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.